# What am I doing wrong(implementing alternative equality with overloading in python)

Tags: python, wrapper, equality

A person asked a question on SO about how to get a list unique function in python with an alternative equality function.

I was thinking it could be done by inheriting from the element class and overloading the equality function

```
import functools
@functools.total_ordering
class ffloat(float):
def __eq__(self,other):
    if floor(self) == floor(other):
        return True
    else:
        return False
def __le__(self,other):
    if self == other:
        return True
    else:
        return float(self) <= float(other)
def __hash__(self):
    return floor(self)


a = map(ffloat,[4.3,8,8.9, 13])


In [41]: a[1] == a[2]
Out[41]: True
```

but

```
In [42]: set(a)
Out[42]: set([4.3, 8.0, 8.9, 13.0])
```

Edit: replaced abs < 1.5 equality with floor equality
Added Hash
P.S. is there a way to make a class factory out of this that a class and two lambda and returns a class that inherits from the first one overriding the needed equality function.

Comment: [(psst)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105215/why-does-this-user-have-such-low-rep-with-so-many-good-answers-questions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a valid equality function, since it's not [transitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation):

`mfloat(0) == mfloat(1) == mfloat(2)`, but `mfloat(0) != mfloat(2)`.

Also note that in order to be used in a set, you must override [`__hash__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) so that the following property holds for all instances a, b of your class:

```
a == b ⇒ hash(a) == hash(b)
```

set finds out that `hash(mfloat(8)) != hash(mfloat(9))`. Since set assumes the above property holds, it concludes that `mfloat(8) != mfloat(9)` without actually calling `__eq__`.

---

In summary, this works:

```
from math import floor
class ffloat(float):
    def __eq__(self,other):
        return floor(self) == floor(other):
    def __hash__(self):
        return floor(self)

a = map(ffloat,[4.3,8,8.9, 13])
print(set(a))
# output: {8.0, 4.3, 13.0}
```

Comment: That is a good point. I did it for floor equality and got the same results.

Comment: @Roman A. Taycher Floor equality (`__eq__ = lambda x,y: floor(x) = floor(y)`) *is* transitive. You probably forgot to implement `__hash__ = lambda self: floor(self)`.

Comment: @Roman A. Taycher Check that you have the correct class. Added a complete example to the answer.